# Put a Windows 10 pc remotely to hibernate from a raspberrypi

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, home-automation

I'm running [homeassistant](https://home-assistant.io) on a RaspberryPi3 in my local network and what I want to achieve is a switch inside homeassistant to switch on and off my computer (Win10)

Apparently my Desktop PC does not support Wake on LAN from a real "shutdown" to S5, so I'm looking for a solution to remotely hibernate it

What I've done/achieved so far:
 - Wake on LAN is working when I manually shutdown with `shutdown /h`
 - remote shutdown is working with `net rpc shutdown -I IPADDRESS -U USERNAME%PASSWORD`

What I've also tried, but failed:
 - running a sshd on Windows (tried with cygwin and openssh port) but failed to start

So the core questions would be either
 - If I can manage to put the Windows machine to hibernate instead of shutdown from remote
 or
 - manage to get WOL working with a completely shutdown machine

Though, Solution 1 would be more convenient to me

Thanks in Advance for any help/hints

Answer (score 4):

I am in the same boat (Home Assistant on a Pi, need to hibernate a Windows computer). I installed [this tool](https://github.com/karpach/remote-shutdown-pc) from Github on the Windows PC. It's a program that listens for GET requests on a specified port, and will Shutdown, Restart, and Hibernate the host Windows computer.

Now, whenever I send a GET to http://windows.computer.IP.address:PORT/SECRET/ the computer hibernates.

Comment: @Martin How does this not answer the question? By using this tool, you can use a Raspberry Pi to remotely put a Windows PC into hibernation. The only other method possible is to use SSH, which the poster already said is not possible.